# How to use Struct in mat files in a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Thanks to all in advance. I am trying to execute the following code in MATLAB and getting accurate results. But when i try this to execute in a for loop, i don't want to write nim_10_boat in the last line of the for loop. I want it should be dynamically placed. Please suggest.

```
`for filenames = {'nim_01_boat', 'nim_10_boat'}
thisfile = filenames{2};
datastruct = load(thisfile);
xyz = datastruct.**nim_10_boat**;
end`
```

when i execute datastruct in the command window
datastruct =

```
         im: [256x256 uint8]
          n: 0.1000
          K: 1
        win: 3
nim_10_boat: [256x256 uint8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically access field names as follows:

```
% a sample struct
S = struct('a', randn(3), 'b', randn(5), 'c', randn(7));
fieldNames = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

for f = 1:length(fieldNames)
   % access field
   thisField = S.(fieldNames{f});
end
```

Note the use of `()` to access field names using variable names.